# Building a PHP script to create new image

Tags: php, html, image

I'm on my way to create a new script for my personal website. I want some kind of function where visitors can write something in an input field and then press generate image.

The script should then take a background image and insert the visitors text on top.

My question is: What is the php code to actually generate the image file and how do i connect the input data to the image?

I do not need full code examples if you don't have the time, i just need the basis practice of how to setup such a system.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php http://www.imagemagick.org/ check your phpinfo() maybe u have it installed. Rest is self explanatory

Comment: Stackoverflow does not do your work. You should show at least minimal self effort in trying to solve your problem.

Comment: I feel my question is fairly within those borders. I only asked for the basic setup of such system. The gentlemen simply provided some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$filename = "layout.jpg";

$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$font = "tahoma.ttf";

$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 50, 50, $black, $font, $_POST['message_from_user']);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($im, null, 100);
imagedestroy($im);
```

layout.jpg is background image, tahoma.ttf is font file

Both files should be placed in the same folder.

This code would generate jpg-image with user string.

More details you would get by searching "gd in php".

Answer (score 1):

do something like this:

```
$text = 'put ur txt here'; 

$height = 25; 

$width = 65; 

$image_p = imagecreate($width, $height); 

$black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0); 

$white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 

$font_size = 14; 



imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white); 

imagejpeg($image_p, 'file name here', 80);
```